# Bypass the cacls confirmation prompt automatically?

Tags: windows, permissions, batch, cacls

I'm working on a custom settings script for Windows that will automate specific settings I want on a new Windows machine or installation. I  grant access to some folders using `cacls` in my script, but I am prompted with the `Y/N` prompt for each listed item. I would like to bypass this by automatically saying "yes" for each folder or file I specify. I am aware of the risks with this and have had no issues thus far. Here is an example of one such directory in my script:

```
cacls "%PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:f
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I am prompted with the Y/N on each item

> I would like to bypass this by automatically saying "yes" for each of these

You can pipe `Y` into `cacls` using `echo`:

```
echo Y| cacls "%PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:f
```

---

> The `CACLS` command does not provide a `/Y` switch to automatically answer `'Y'` to the `Y/N` prompt. However, you can pipe the `'Y'` character into the `CACLS` command using `ECHO`, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> ECHO Y| CACLS filename /g username:permission
> ```

Source [Cacls - Modify Access Control List - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html)

Removed space before pipe to fix command

Answer (score 8):

Use this syntax:

```
echo y| cacls.exe [options]...
```

Note that the command-line needs to be written exactly as above, including the
blanks (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229176/using-cacls-exe-in-a-batch-file-with-auto-answer)).

Answer (score 1):

Switch to [icacls.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) (built into Windows), which doesn't have this prompt.

Answer (score 0):

One quick note about the best answer, need to remove the space just before the pipe

Y|  works

Y | doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).